# Algorithm to expand tables out from center ER diagram Javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, entity-relationship

I'm creating an ER diagram using `React`, and I'm trying to figure out a way to populate tables in a way that they expand out from a center.

The tables are draggable so the users can move them however they want (I already got this done), but initially when they are first loaded in, I'm hardcoding the initial coordinates of the tables. It would be nice to have this done programmatically.

I'm having trouble coming up with a math that takes a center coordinate and places the tables around it, depending on how many tables are populated.

So far I can only find information about ER diagrams themselves, not the math.